# removing XUL menu dynamically

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon, xul

I'm having an issue where I can't remove a menu that was created dynamically in my extension. I can get the menu object with `document.getElementById` or by using the jquery stuff like I have below. Basically, the user clicks the 'remove' menu item, and it's supposed to remove the parent menu (there are 2 parents because it goes menu > popup > menuitem (clicked) ).

Alert spits out the proper `id` for what I want to remove. `removeObj.remove();` crashes the extension. The last line doesn't seem to do anything (except if  click remove the second time it no longer can find the `id`), however it's still visible in the UI.

Code:

```
var jObj = $(menuObject);
var removeObj = $(jObj).parent().parent();
var id = removeObj.attr('id');
alert(id);
//removeObj.remove();           
$(removeObj).parent().removeChild(document.getElementById(id));
```

it's not due to jquery. i have written this and it completely disables the right click menu after execution (but returns the correct id location in the if-case)

```
                var mainMenu = document.getElementById('rclickMenu_MenuPopupContainer');
                var toRemove = document.getElementById("rclickMenu_"+main);
                for(var i=0; i < mainMenu.children.length; i++){
                    if(mainMenu.children[i].getAttribute('id') == toRemove.getAttribute('id')){
                        alert(toRemove.getAttribute('id'));
                        //mainMenu.removeItemAt(i); 
                        mainMenu.removeChild(toRemove);
                    }
                }
```

Comment: it looks like you are using jQuery code, but jQuery does not exist in browser code, so why are you using jQuery code?

Comment: you can include jquery in your code to be able to use it. even if i don't use it, it doesn't work. ex. var mainMenu = document.getElementById('mainmenu'); mainMenu.removeChild(document.getElementById('clickeditem'));

Comment: huh? are you using jQuery or not?

Comment: if you are then you should not, and that's probably why your code dnw

Comment: i am using jquery. but even if i dont use it and use document.getElementById like I showed, it doesn't work. in other words, whether I'm using jquery or not, I can't remove a menu item. do you know how to remove it?

Answer (score 0):

Do:

```
let (ele = document.getElementById(id)) {
    ele.parentNode.removeChild(ele);
}
```

Comment: this crashes my right click menu, the same as the second bit of code i added to my original question. i'm not sure why this is happening. the for loop i made shows that i have the right root element, and the element i'm trying to remove is a child of that, but when i go to actually remove it, nothing works.

Comment: i did, it's in the question, look at the second code section. how much of it would you like to see? it's quite long